# How do I use external files as tables in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to make a program that chooses a random monster from a list, give the user a list of usable weapons, and allows them to choose which weapon to use. I want to use external files to store data for the weapons instead of adding the tables in the Lua file itself. I have tried using Lua files to store the data as a table.

I have a file called sword.lua in the same folder as the program I want to access it's information. It contains

```
sword = {'sword', '10', '1', '100'}
```

I am trying to access the information using

```
wep = io.open("sword.lua", "r")
print(wep:read("*a"))
print(wep[1])
```

The first print returns all of the text in the file which is

```
"sword = {'sword', '10', '1', '100'}"
```

and the second is supposed to return the first item in the table. Every time I do this, I get a nil value from the second print. The file is being read, as indicated by the first print listing the text, but how do I make it read the file as a table that I can use in my program.

Comment: "*the second is supposed to return the first item in the table*" Why? Why would you expect printing a *file* (that's what `wep` is) to return an item in a table described by a string stored in that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load a table from a file use the `require` function.  For example, save

```
return { 'sword', '10', '1', '100' }
```

as `sword.lua`.  Why do I just use `return` instead of assigning to a variable?  It's because that is much more flexible.  If I assign the table to the variable `sword` inside the file, I'm sort of locked into that naming convention and furthermore I pollute the global namespace, making name collisions more likely.

With the above solution I can also assign to a local variable, like so

```
local sword = require("sword")
print(table.concat(sword,", "))
```

Another advantage is that calls to `require` are cached, i.e. even if you `require("sword")` many times, you only pay the cost for loading once.  But keep in mind that because of caching you always get a handle to the same table, i.e. if you alter the table returned from `require("sword")`, these modifications will be shared by all instances.

[Example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b3uWuriLSdkGRRZy)